# Using Ghost as a Headless CMS

Tags: gatsby, ghost-blog

I am interested in using Ghost as a headless CMS for a Gatsby site.  What I am wondering, though, how flexible Ghost is as a headless cms.  For instance, for the site that I am building now - I have different pages with different content structures, a news section and more.

In Wordpress, I would simply use different content types for the different page types.  I am wondering, though, is something like this possible in Ghost?

If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Ghost you can add tags to define different post types and use the Content API filter option to retrieve them:
https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/content/#parameters